# Find matrices which generate a given set of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

I've got a finite set of vectors in $Z^3$, which I know to be of the form $A^{i_1}B^{i_2}A^{i_3}B^{i_4}\dots v$ for some unknown vector $v\in Z^3$ and two unknown matrices $A$ and $B$ with integer entries, and where $i_j$ are small non-negative integers.   How do I compute $v$ and $A$ and $B$?

Comment: What does "small" mean?

Comment: Maybe 50 or 100.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer, but with very high probability this question is undecidable, since it is clearly closely connected with the *vector reachability* problem for integral matrix semigroups, which is in general undecidable. For a very nice survey, see this paper by [Halava, Harju, Hirvensalo](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=A5FF78A97A2165C4EA721FD99D806201?doi=10.1.1.154.9129&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (2006, but doubt that any great advances have occured since then).